tcshell bind-key for !^ first argument of the previous command
The tcsh environment I am currently using does not bind M-. to obtain the first argument of the previous CLI command as I would like.
Running !^ M-space provides the desired behavior, and I would like this behavior bound to M-. (The key sequence alt dot).
How can I use bind-key get the behavior of !^ followed by M-space when typing M-.
I have tried the following:
bindkey "^[." !^
Which produces Bad ! arg selector
and
bindkey "^[." '!^'
which produces
Bad command name: "^[."
and
bindkey -c "^[." 'echo !^' which produces Bad command name: echo "^[."
I have had this binding set up elsewhere in another system's ~/dotfiles but don't currently have access to that system.
I am fairly certain that I originally found a solution to this question years ago on a SO site; just can't find it today.
This question: previous args says that bash binds M-. to this behavior.
Seems like tcsh does not do the same by default.

This is a better question for [unix.se] than Stack Overflow. (I'd argue that the previous question you linked is off-topic too and should have been migrated/closed as well).
